# Bukkit plugin already initialized

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

When I am testing my plugin the following exception gets thrown: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!`

The plugin works but the event "AdventureMode" does not, here is the code:

```
package net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.cmd.Feed;
import net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.cmd.Fly;
import net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.cmd.Heal;
import net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.cmd.Kits;
import net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.cmd.Spacepvp;
import net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.cmd.gamemode;
import net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.util.AdventureMode;
import net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.util.ChatFormatting;
import net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.util.Messages;

public class MainClass extends JavaPlugin implements ChatFormatting, Messages{


    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(tag + green + enabled + orange + brand);

        registerCommands();
        registerEvents();

    }

    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(tag + red + disabled + orange + brand);
    }

    public void registerCommands() {

        getCommand("spacepvp").setExecutor(new Spacepvp());
        getCommand("kit").setExecutor(new Kits());
        getCommand("heal").setExecutor(new Heal());
        getCommand("feed").setExecutor(new Feed());
        getCommand("fly").setExecutor(new Fly());
        getCommand("gamemode").setExecutor(new gamemode());

    }

    public void registerEvents() {
        PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();

         pm.registerEvents(new AdventureMode(), this);
    }


}
```

I do not have any other plugins with the same class and the test server directory is empty.

The error

```
[07:41:11 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling SpacePVP v0.4 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:122) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:67) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.cmd.Fly.<init>(Fly.java:10) ~[?:?]
        at net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.MainClass.registerCommands(MainClass.java:40) ~[?:?]
        at net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.MainClass.onEnable(MainClass.java:24) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:271) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:376) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:326) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:421) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:382) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:337) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:272) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:544) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initial initialization
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:125) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:67) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.MainClass.<init>(MainClass.java:18) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:76) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:129) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:329) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:301) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:204) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: Is that the only class that extends `JavaPlugin` ? Test the plugin without any other plugins.

Comment: maybe `Fly` is the other class... StackTrace indicates that the constructor at line 10 of Fly.java is *calling* the constructor of JavaPlugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs during the construction of the `Fly` instance, as annotated in the following stack trace excerpt.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:122) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:67) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]

--->    at net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.cmd.Fly.<init>(Fly.java:10) ~[?:?]

        at net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.MainClass.registerCommands(MainClass.java:40) ~[?:?]
        at net.battleheroes.spigot.spacepvp.MainClass.onEnable(MainClass.java:24) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:271) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-2b6c9f4]
```

Alas, that is all I can tell you without additional source code. Examine `Fly`'s constructor and/or those of its superclasses, making sure there are no attempts to create another instance of a `JavaPlugin` derived class. I would hazard a guess that `Fly` is being **extended** from `MainClass` or `JavaPlugin`.